# Intersection Observer on a class with multiple elements visible at the same time

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, intersection, intersection-observer

I've been struggling for 2 days with an Intersection Observer

I have an App.vue, where there are a bunch of boxes (`.box`), you discover more boxes as you scroll, and there can be multiple boxes visible at the same time in the viewport.

```
  mounted() {
    this.setupIntersectionObserver()
  }
```

```
setupIntersectionObserver(){
  document.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach((i) => {
      if (i) {
          const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
              observerCallback(entries, observer, i)
          },
          {threshold: 0});    
          observer.observe(i);
      }
  })

  const observerCallback = (entries, observer, header) => {
      entries.forEach((entry, i) => {
           if (entry.isIntersecting) {
               entry.target.classList.add('visible')
           }
           else {
               entry.target.classList.remove('visible')
           }
      });
  };
},
```

With this code, on scroll, only one of the `.box` gets the `.visible` class at any time, even though multiple `.box` are visible at the same time.

I can't manage to make the Intersection Observer work correctly, it's always either considering all boxes, or a single box.

How would you handle this? Knowing that I'm trying not to use `$refs` in this situation.
This code is in `App.vue` and the `.box` are from a `Box.vue` component.

Answer (score 0):

For the intersection Observer I would suggest to use just one observer to observe many boxes.
Currently you are creating an observer for every box.
I would also suggest to provide an array of values as your threshold.
such as [0.2,0.8]
what this threshold means that it will trigger the call back function when either 20% or 80% of the box is visible.This helps you catch the in and the out.

Comment: Thanks for your input. So, I've tried this also, with "this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);" with then "  document.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach((element) => {
    this.observer.observe(element);
  });" but no luck. And I need the treshold to be at 0 so that as soon as there's 1px in it triggers the visible class for all boxes (for design and other app logic reasons)